# Using custom JavaScript widget within Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, custom

On another project (not salesforce) a few years back, I used the [jQuery Autocomplete widget](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to search content/fields within a tabbed container. Here's an animated screenshot:

[image]

Can I do something like this in a Lightning App? I'm wondering what's involved in integrating a custom UI like this within a Lightning app (or maybe there's similar functionality already baked in?).

(Currently we're using mostly Aura components, but some LWC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I do something like this in a Lightning App?

Yes.

> I'm wondering what's involved in integrating a custom UI like this within a Lightning app.

In *most* cases, it's as simple as setting the root of the app to manual DOM control (e.g. `<div lwc:dom="manual">`, importing jQuery directly or by static resource, and then calling the initialization code in your LWC component.

---

Example:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { jQuery } from 'c/jQuery';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        // Do whatever you need to initialize your data here //
        jQuery(this.template.querySelector('div')).initializejQueryPluginThatDoesTheThing();
    }
}
```

---

```
<div lwc:dom="manual">
</div>
```

---

The alternative is loadScript:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import jQuery from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jquery';
import jQueryFilterPlugin from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jQueryFilterPlugin';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
        // Do whatever you need to initialize your data here //
        await Promise.all([loadScript(this, jQuery), loadScript(this, jQueryFilterPlugin)]);
        $(this.template.querySelector('div')).initializejQueryPluginThatDoesTheThing();
    }
}
```

---

You can easily build this in LWC, by way of lightning-tabset, lightning-tab, lightning-checkbox-group, lightning-card, and lightning-input (plus maybe a few others). The amount of effort required should probably only take a few hours to days if you use the documentation to help you build it. It certainly possible to build it natively without too much effort, but I can certainly understand not wanting to do so if you already have a solution built.

Comment: It is very important to note though that if you try to publish this as managed package, your sec review will fail because these auto complete controls rely on `position:` CSS attribute to overlay above other content and that is a no-no from sec review team. We had to have ours inlined among other controls causing it to just push everything down. (as we'd rather have ugly package than no package)

Comment: @zaitsman Hmm. I'm tempted to talk to someone about this. What do they think modal dialogs are? Lookup fields? That's an absolutely insane restriction.

Comment: oh, if you can convince them that would allow me to enhance the UI in my app. This did sound crazy. The actual name for this they used in the failure report was `Lightning: CSS Outside Component` and the notes were `Avoid to use position fixed/relative/absolute since it could affect to the visibility of other components.`